# Getting the error message “Invalid or damaged bootable partition” but only on a reboot

Tags: windows, boot, reboot

My son has a Dell Optiplex 9020, i7 4th Generation, 8GB RAM, Nvidia GTX 1030 video card, with a 1TB SATA hard drive. And the system shows the following error message only on reboot:

> “Invalid or damaged bootable partition.”

Only OS is Windows 10 Pro. UEFI mode and secure boot disabled, system is in Legacy Boot mode.

If powered on, it boot fine and everything works as expected.

If a reboot occurs, the system halts just after the BIOS/UEFI firmware splash screen and it says "Invalid or damaged bootable partition" and just hangs there. If I power off and back on, everything works as expected.

We have booted up the install media and done a Repair at the command prompt...

- `bootrec /FixMbr` <- Completes with no issues.
- `bootrec /FixBoot` <- Returns "Access denied"
- `bootrec /ScanOS` <- Shows [1] F:\Windows and [2] F:\Windows.old\Windows
- `bootrec /RebuildBcd` <- Shows both but returns "Element not found" when you select either or all to add

Otherwise everything is working normally... But this causes a problem with Windows updates that reboots randomly at night or at other times a reboot is necessary.

Any thoughts on how to go about correcting this, or would the best solution simply be to reinstall Windows?

Comment: 1. turn off UEFI in BIOS, stay with Legacy boot
2. isn't Windows in UEFI mode?
3. what is the boot order, isn't the UEFI first?
4. what happens when you press space at the "Invalid..." message?

Comment: @pbies 1) EFI is turned off in BIOS, the system is in Legacy Mode, 2) No, Windows is not in UEFI mode, there is no UEFI partition, only MBR boot record, 3) USB Device, Optical Drive, HDD, and NIC, 4) Nothing, it just hangs there and does nothing.

Comment: @pbies Actually, I think I just figured it out... He had an old MP3 player plugged into a USB port on the back of the computer. Once unplugged it seems to be working normally now. Very odd...

Comment: Seems like player was taking the boot process and when missing OS on it, it was stopping other devices from booting. Good to hear that solved your problem.

Comment: @pbies Yeah, it's odd. I think the reason a cold boot worked is because the if the power is removed/reapplied to the MP3 player it would reboot (bad battery), and by the time the BIOS scanned the bootable devices, the MP3 player wasn't initialized yet thus didn't look like a disk. On a reboot of the system it never lost power and was active and appeared to be a disk to the BIOS, unclear why it thought it was bootable though. Odd scenario, but it seems to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an old USB MP3 player that was connected to a USB port. Disconnecting the device allowed the system to boot or reboot without issue.